# Multiple users trying to getting Office 365 profile data using power shell commands in asp.net

Tags: c#, asp.net, powershell, office365

We are using `powershell` commands to get user profile data when user logged in to our website using `Office 365` credentials. Now we are getting problem when 4 to 6 users come to my website and hit the login button of `office 365`, When ever I pass these credentials to `powershell`, 3 users sessions are created but not for other users. I googled myself and found the link which states the same. Here is the link:

https://4sysops.com/forums/topic/office-365-you-have-exceeded-the-maximum-number-of-connections-allowed-3/

Can I have any resolution for this as I need to expect multiple users to my website at a time.

Here is My Sample Code:

```
 try
        {
            Collection<PSObject> userList = null;
            // Create Initial Session State for runspace.
            InitialSessionState initialSession = InitialSessionState.CreateDefault();
            initialSession.ImportPSModule(new[] { "MSOnline" });
            // Create credential object.
            PSCredential credential = new PSCredential(UserCredential.UserName, UserCredential.Password);
            // Create command to connect office 365.
            Command connectCommand = new Command("Connect-MsolService");
            connectCommand.Parameters.Add((new CommandParameter("Credential", credential)));
            Command getUserCommand = new Command("Get-MsolUser");
            getUserCommand.Parameters.Add((new CommandParameter("UserPrincipalName", UserCredential.UserName)));

            using (Runspace psRunSpace = RunspaceFactory.CreateRunspace(initialSession))
            {
                // Open runspace.
                psRunSpace.Open();
                //Iterate through each command and executes it.
                foreach (var com in new Command[] { connectCommand, getUserCommand })
                {
                    var pipe = psRunSpace.CreatePipeline();
                    pipe.Commands.Add(com);
                    // Execute command and generate results and errors (if any).
                    Collection<PSObject> results = pipe.Invoke();
                    var error = pipe.Error.ReadToEnd();
                    if (error.Count > 0 && com == connectCommand)
                    {
                        //    MessageBox.Show(error[0].ToString(), "Problem in login");
                        //this.Close();
                        return null;
                    }
                    if (error.Count > 0 && com == getUserCommand)
                    {
                        // MessageBox.Show(error[0].ToString(), "Problem in getting users");
                        // this.Close();
                        return null;
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        userList = results;
                        Session["office365userslist"] = userList;

                    }
                }
                // Close the runspace.
                psRunSpace.Close();
            }
            return userList;
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            Response.Write(ex.Message);
            throw;
        }
```

Answer (score 1):

PowerShell is not recommended for such kind of scenario (Web App).

To get the user profile of a user in your web app, I suggest you using the [Microsoft Graph API - Get user](http://graph.microsoft.io/en-us/docs/api-reference/v1.0/api/user_get).

Request:

```
GET https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/me
```

Response:

```
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Content-type: application/json
Content-length: 491

{
  "businessPhones": [
       "businessPhones-value"
   ],
   "displayName": "displayName-value",
   "givenName": "givenName-value",
   "jobTitle": "jobTitle-value",
   "mail": "mail-value",
   "mobilePhone": "mobilePhone-value",
   "officeLocation": "officeLocation-value",
   "preferredLanguage": "preferredLanguage-value",
   "surname": "surname-value",
   "userPrincipalName": "userPrincipalName-value",
   "id": "id-value"
}
```

About how to integrate the Microsoft Graph API in your web app, you can reference the sample project on [GitHub Office 365 Starter Project for ASP.NET MVC](https://github.com/OfficeDev/O365-ASPNETMVC-Start).

UPDATE#1

> Is there any alternative to add disclaimer text in exchange server through API?

But the graph API does not provide the function to set the disclaimer html. You can submit a feedback to [Office 365 Developer Platform User Voice](https://officespdev.uservoice.com/).

In this scenario, the possible workaround could be sequencing the requests.

For example, put all the requests in a queue and handle requests in 3 threads (max concurrency).

Sample code for your reference:

```
public class SequencedRequestsDemo
{
    private class SampleRequest
    {
        public string ActionName { get; set; }

        public UserCredential UserCredential { get; set; }
    }

    private class UserCredential
    {
        public string UserName { get; set; }

        public string Password { get; set; }
    }

    private ConcurrentQueue<SampleRequest> _queue = new ConcurrentQueue<SampleRequest>();

    public override void Run()
    {
        _queue.Enqueue(new SampleRequest { ActionName = "action_name1", UserCredential = new UserCredential() });

        _queue.Enqueue(new SampleRequest { ActionName = "action_name2", UserCredential = new UserCredential() });

        _queue.Enqueue(new SampleRequest { ActionName = "action_name3", UserCredential = new UserCredential() });

        _queue.Enqueue(new SampleRequest { ActionName = "action_name4", UserCredential = new UserCredential() });

        _queue.Enqueue(new SampleRequest { ActionName = "action_name5", UserCredential = new UserCredential() });

        _queue.Enqueue(new SampleRequest { ActionName = "action_name6", UserCredential = new UserCredential() });

        var thread1 = new System.Threading.Thread(() => {
            WaitForRequest();
        });

        var thread2 = new System.Threading.Thread(() => {
            WaitForRequest();
        });

        var thread3 = new System.Threading.Thread(() => {
            WaitForRequest();
        });

        thread1.Start();

        thread2.Start();

        thread3.Start();
    }

    private void WaitForRequest()
    {
        while(true)
        {
            SampleRequest request;

            if (_queue.TryDequeue(out request))
            {
                HandleRequest(request);
            }
            else
            {
                System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(1000);
            }
        }
    }

    private void HandleRequest(SampleRequest request)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Handle request {0} - {1}", request.ActionName, System.Threading.Thread.CurrentThread.ManagedThreadId);
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks Chen,  We are setting up disclaimer html by using power shell. So I written all my code in power shell. Is there any alternative to add disclaimer text in exchange server through API?

Comment: The graph API does not provide the function to set the disclaimer html, in this case, I think the possible workaround could be sequencing the requests, see the update#1 in my answer.

Comment: Hi Chen. i just update my sample code. Please check it once.How can i make it as sequence?? Can you suggest..

Comment: I updated my answer to add the sample code, you can wrapper the user requests in a PowerShellUserReqeust class and then handle the request in 3 different threads.